# No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker to a known managed provider native type error while clicking on save button

Tags: c#, winforms

i have declared print_dec,print_srno,oneclick_sale,enable_tracking and not_for_sale as bool data type and stored trrue/ false and bit data types are declared in database defination when i click on the save button it gave me the error
"No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker to a known managed provider native type".
here is my code

```
 private void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {//start of body of save btn

            get_checkbox();
            Connectionclass conect = new Connectionclass();//ceating object of connectionclass
            conect.myconnection();//calling my connection method through conect object
            try//try method
            {//start of body of try
                get_group();//calling get group method
                get_brand();//calling get brand method
                get_unit();//calling get_unit method
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("save_product", conect.conn);//creating the object of sqlcommand
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;//defining the command type as stored procedure
                cmd.Connection = conect.conn;//assigning cmd connection string
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group_id", group_id);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand_id", brand_id);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit_id",unit_id);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_code", itemcodetxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", Productnametxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_name", printnametxt);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchase_price", Purchasepricetxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale__price", salepricetxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@min_sale_price", Minsalepricetxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M_R_P", MRPtxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@openoing_stock", Openingstocktxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opening_stock_value", openingstockvaluetxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_discount", salediscounttxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Low_level_limit", lowlevellimittxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_type", Producttypecmb.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_description", productdescriptiontxt.Text);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_description",print_desc);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_srno", print_srno);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oneclick_sale", oneclick_sale);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enable_tracking", enable_tracking);//passing text box vale to database column
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@not_for_sale", not);//passing text box vale to database column
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add product", "group", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);//showing message to user
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)//if statement
                //{//start of body of if 
                    //if (nametxt.Text == "")//if condition
                    //{//start of body of if
                        //MessageBox.Show("name is required");//this will show the message box to the user
                    //}//end of body of if
                    //else condition
                    {//start of body of if
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//executing the above queries
                        MessageBox.Show("group successfully added");//messaage box that will show that group is added
                        //cleargroup();//calling cleargroup method 
                    }//end of body of if
                //}//end of body of if
                
            }//end of body of try                                            
            catch (Exception ex)//exception method that will through exception
            {//start of body of catch
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "saving error");//a message box that will show error if try not run
            }//end of body of catch
            finally
            {
                conect.conn.Close();//closing database connection
            }
        }//end of body of save btn
```

here is my sql server code

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[save_product]
@group_id int,
@brand_id int,
@unit_id int,
@Item_code varchar(255),
@product_name varchar(255),
@print_name varchar(255),
@purchase_price float,
@sale__price float,
@min_sale_price float,
@M_R_P float,
@openoing_stock varchar(255),
@opening_stock_value float,
@sale_discount varchar(3),
@Low_level_limit varchar(255),
@product_type varchar(255),
@serial_no varchar(255),
@product_description varchar(255),
@print_description bit,
@print_srno bit,
@oneclick_sale bit,
@enable_tracking bit,
@not_for_sale bit
as
begin
insert into add_product (
group_id,
brand_id,
unit_id,
Item_code,
product_name,
print_name,
purchase_price,
sale__price,
min_sale_price,
M_R_P,
openoing_stock,
opening_stock_value,
sale_discount,
Low_level_limit,
product_type,
serial_no,
product_description,
print_description,
print_srno,
oneclick_sale,
enable_tracking,
not_for_sale
)
values
(
@group_id,
@brand_id ,
@unit_id ,
@Item_code ,
@product_name ,
@print_name ,
@purchase_price ,
@sale__price ,
@min_sale_price ,
@M_R_P ,
@openoing_stock ,
@opening_stock_value ,
@sale_discount ,
@Low_level_limit ,
@product_type ,
@serial_no ,
@product_description,
@print_description ,
@print_srno ,
@oneclick_sale,
@enable_tracking ,
@not_for_sale 
)

end
```

[here is my exception error picture][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAufM.png

Comment: Print stack trace using `ex.ToString()` in either `MessageBox` or `Console` that should give you line. See if you have `ex.InnerException` available. If yes, print `e.InnerException.Message`. That should give you what it is in the query that is causing the problem. If you cannot figure out post it here.

Comment: Does one of the variables you mention in any of the AddWithValue calls happen to be a DateTimePicker control?

Comment: @KlausGütter no sir

Comment: @vish its System.argumentExceptin:

Comment: then it would be one of the arguments to stored proc. Is backend SQL Server? And could you post the prototype\signature of `save_product` along with parameters?

Comment: @vish i have added the sql server code above

Comment: @shahidabbas there is mismatch between parameters; procedure and `add_product` has `serial_no`. Your C# code does not.

Comment: @vish stilll same error here is the screenshot of exceptio  error https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAufM.png

Comment: @shahidabbas This is a different error. This error is `no mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Form.TextBox`. So I would guess you are passing `System.Windows.Form.TextBox` to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` calls as parameter. Could you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is showed up because you're passing the actual Textbox object, instead of its value (Text property in this case).

for example, instead of:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_name", printnametxt);
```

write:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@print_name", printnametxt.Text);
```